# How to approach persistent state multiplayer games on iOS (+PHP/mySql)

Tags: php, mysql, ios, persistence

**Proposed Situation:**
Imagine an iPhone game: A farm, comprised of 100 plantable crop squares. Each crop square has two possible states (EMPTY or PLANTED). The farm object (*100 crop squares*) is stored in a mySql table as a json string object. We expose a php web service for retrieving/updating the farm from the game.

**Question:**
Have you been down this road before? What are some good approaches for managing the 'farm object' so that multiple users can be updating / retrieving the same farm simultaneously from their respective iPhones, without any conficts? Will I be required to start from scratch and re-invent the wheel (subversion?) or is there already some appropriate code out there?

Comment: Using MySQL to store opaque serialized data blobs is one of the classic blunders, right after getting involved in a land war in Asia.  If you want to use a relational database, make a real schema.  If you want to store JSON, use MongoDB or CouchDB that understand JSON natively and can work with it.

Comment: For the application described, I would tend to agree with @chaos